# Excel: array sum if

Tags: excel

I have what seems to be a simple issue but I can't resolve it.

I have two columns. One will only ever be a value of 5,10,20,40,50,60,80,signed.

The other is just a currency value.

I've been looking into arrays to see if I can simplify this formula but I'm failing.

Right now,  I need the formula to evaluate if the first column is a number and is greater than or equal to 40 but less than 80. If it is, it needs to multiply against the currency value next to it and return the total of the entire set of entries for which this is true.

Can someone help me formulate this as I just end up with a massive sum if. Surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8>=40)*($A$1:$A$8<80),$A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I should mention that 'signed' is a part of the first column. Does this affect output? I guess the formula could be extended to translate signed into '100'

Comment: Yes, it matters.  This formula will fail if there is text in the referenced values. @JohnHalstead.

Comment: @JohnHalstead see edit.  You may need to refresh the screen

Comment: So,  final question : what are the asterisks doing here. In English, this translates to:

Comment: When you do mathematical operations on Boolean values it reverts them to there Bit component True = 1 and False = 0.  So the `*` is the same as AND.

Comment: Re "This formula will fail if there is text in the referenced values", this is only because the 'product' version of SUMPRODUCT is being used here. The native, comma-separated-argument version handles text: =SUMPRODUCT(0+($A$1:$A$7>=40),0+($A$1:$A$7<80),$A$1:$A$7,$B$1:$B$7)

Comment: @XORLX Good to know.  I will adjust the answer.

Comment: Thank you all. I had to run off so my follow up question was supposed to be "So,  final question : what are the asterisks doing here. In English, this translates to: sum of : if a1 to a8 is a number, then,  if a1 to a8 is less than 80, multiplied by a1 to a8 multiplied by greater then or equal to 40"

Comment: @JohnHalstead please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Back. This is actually not quite what I'm trying to do as the second answer avoided the use of arrays.

Comment: Not sure I understand. could you elaborate? @JohnHalstead